# google drive api variable attrib value

Tags: google-drive-api

I will have some documents on my drive that will be used as templates, on those templates I will have some variables like #name, #adresss, #Date, etc.etc.

I will need to create a new document based on the template (Copy to a new doc) and change the variables with real data from my webapp

Which is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms...

1. Learn how to do Google Oauth
2. Learn how to use the Drive API
3. Use the Drive API to download a file to your app.
4. Your app does the token replacement
5. Upload the resulting file to Drive

The only thing to be careful about is how much formatting you lose during step 3, which in turn is influenced by what format (HTML, Word, OO, etc) you choose to use for step 4.